# how to limit download generated link only for specific pc using php

Tags: php, download

i have a php and mysql script for downloading files.
script changed from openupload script and we have changed download only with user , database and php with download id and limited in file, traffic and time.
exdomain.com/download.php?111222

when an user generated link can download this id link with many systems if logged with downloaded user.

i want link to work only on one PC and the first generated link computer.

May I ask if anyone can suggest a solution?

Comment: no idea what you just asked

Comment: so have the download script count how many times that ID has been requested. `if ($total_requests == 0) { allow download; $total_requests++; } else { forbid download }`

Comment: can you please reword your question? hard to understand.

Comment: *mr.question* has not made a very clear question. If you have *mr.question* as a username, you should probably be good at asking clear questions.

Answer (score 1):

As I understand the question, you want to prevent that users share their account details to download files on other PCs.
Therefore, I thought about a few solutions:

1. Protect the file itself [HWID Protection or sth.] ***best***
2. Protect the login, so users can only login on one device once
3. Log the IPs on every login, develop a script which checks for different IPs a day -> different PCs (mostly)

Only the first solution will work 100%, because as soon as the user downloaded the file, he can share it with anyone. So it's most important to protect the program, than protecting the download page.